# Choose which view to load when app runs in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know which is the best way to do this and how to implement it:
When the app runs, it checks if there's a value in user defaults 
`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") == nil` If the value is nil, I would like the app to redirect to a view called `LoginViewController`, and if not nil, go to `MainViewController`. Both clases are `UIViewController`.
I was thinking in create a new `RedirectViewController` as initial View Controller, and check it there, but it doesn't work, it doesn't redirects:

```
class RedirectOnStart: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") == nil {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginRegisterSegue", sender: nil)

    } else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("mainViewSegue", sender: nil)
    }
  }


  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "loginRegisterSegue" {

        let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! LoginRegisterViewController
    }

    if segue.identifier == "mainViewSegue" {

        let nav = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController

    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your scenario starts with "when the app runs" you should consider working in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` directly.

For example:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow()

    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("uid") == nil {
        self.window?.rootViewController = LoginController()

    } else {
        self.window?.rootViewController = MainController()
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that the above answer is written for Objective-C not Swift; currently written it won't load up the actual view controller you want. Below code will work within 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions".

1. make sure you have a userdefault (in my case "Username") for the statement to check for. If it find it's empty; that'll direct you to "SignUpVC", if it's not empty, it'll direct you to "LoginVC".
2. you'll need to ensure you have set your identifiers for your View Controllers on your storyboard (in my case, 'Main').
3. after this, make sure you have some sort of method setup to go from Login/Signup to the next set of screens, such as a segue.

*Hope this helps someone out there, Have a great day.*

**Swift 3:**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    self.window = UIWindow()

    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "Username") == nil {
      let signupViewCon = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpVC")
      self.window?.rootViewController = signupViewCon

    } else {
      let loginViewCon = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC")
      self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewCon
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }
```